# Must Declare Scalar Variable error even though it's declared

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I have a variable I've declared as an nvarchar but when I use it in the code and execute it, I get the "Must declare the scalar variable @C".

I've already done this so why am I getting the error? It doesn't happen to my other variable @T.

```sql
        DECLARE @T NVARCHAR(3) 
        SET @T = 'ABC'
        DECLARE @C NVARCHAR(2)
        SET @C = '26'
        DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @SQL =
           'SELECT ' + @C + ' AS CLASS, 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1_'+@T+') T1,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T2_'+@T+') T2,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T3_'+@T+') T3'
exec (@SQL)
```

I could as easily just write `SELECT '26' AS Class` (which works) but eventually I want to wrap this in a stored procedure where @C is passed as a parameter.

Comment: I didn't find any `@C` variable in your query, perhaps it should be `@CID`.

Comment: As I see, you didn't declare variable C. You declared variable CID, my friend :))

Comment: Sorry guys, that was a typo on my part when copying and pasting across. Correcting it now. Variable is declared as above.

Comment: So, it was a typo, and now you've edited the question so that it doesn't even make sense because it doesn't cause the error any more. I'd suggest deletion instead.

Comment: @Damien_the_unbeliever Ok my friend will try again. It still errors. The matter of the typo was neither here nor there. As it presents on my screen is how it is in my code and I still get an error.

Comment: **an** error yes. But I'm willing to bet it's a completely *different* error to the one currently mentioned throughout the question. Help people help you. When errors messages change, don't just tell us that you still get an error.

Comment: Or, in the alternative, you're not showing enough code - because the above code compiles fine in its first pass when `@C` is in scope and complains (from the `exec`) that `T1_ABC` doesn't exist.